# ¿Cual puede ser el problema con background-image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, sass

sass

div

```
margin: 10px auto
width: 100%
max-width: 720px
min-width: 240px
background-image: url(..imagenes/img1.jpg)
```

jquery

```
var anchoS=($("div").width())*0.75;
$("div").css("height",anchoS);
$(window).resize(function(){
    anchoS=($("div").width())*0.75;
    $("div").css("height",anchoS);
});
```

Quiero hacer un div con fondo que sea responsive
probé con todo hasta poniendo 'imagenes/img1.jpg' en lugar de los 3 puntos y nada como hago para colocar una imagen de fondo en ese div, con esas dimensiones.

Comment: revisa bien la ruta de tu imagen, y me parece que tienes un error al momento de retroceder en la carpeta tienes `url(..imagenes/img1.jpg)` y seria `url(../imagenes/img1.jpg)`, tambien revisa la extension de tu imagen que puede que no sea .jpg si no otra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Revisa la ubicación de la imagen, recuerda que el background-image toma la url (sin usar frameworks) justo desde donde tienes el archivo de css con ese estilo. Por lo que si tienes una estructura de carpetas como la siguiente:

```
Proyecto
  -imagenes
     --img1.jpg
  -CSS
     --estilos.css
  -JS
```

Debes tener cuidado con la ruta que vas a colocar. Fijate que si estas en estilos.css debes subir un nivel (para estar a la altura de imagenes) y luego entrar en imagenes para poder seleccionar img1.jpg por lo que la ruta quedaría así:

```
background-image: url(../imagenes/img1.jpg)
```

Recuerda que "../" sirve para subir un nivel en el directorio de tu proyecto.

**2)** Por otra parte ubica la imagen, abre el archivo y asegurate que es formato "jpg" y no "jpeg" o "png" o algún otro porque esto influye y si colocas el equivocado no se seleccionará la imagen y por lo tanto no podrás observarla como fondo del div. Así que si tu imagen es por ejemplo "png" al final de la url debe ser img1.png y no img1.jpg

**3)** Para el responsive te recomendaría que utilices algún framework front-end. Ya que te simplificará enormemente el trabajo de cara al diseño responsive. Si sigues creando el responsive "manual" perderás mucho tiempo codificando en jquery y diseñando media queries.

Bootstrap es un framework perfecto para el diseño responsive, es facil de instalar y esta conformado de una hoja de estilos (.css) y un archivo javascript (.js). Te recomiendo un framework porque la imagen de fondo no será lo único que deberás o desearás colocar responsive... Para que se pueda ver correctamente en tabletas y telefonos móviles todo debe ser responsive. Los inputs, las tablas de resultados... cada uno de los elementos visuales de los formularios deberá poseer esta característica. Puedes leer sobre bootstrap y descargarlo en [la página oficial de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com)

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo!

Comment: utilice bootstrap y lei por encima los css, no entiendo cual fue el error pero funciono jaja gracias en serio, pero yo lo tenia escrito url(..imagenes/img1.jpg) y no me funcionaba pero ahora si.. x.x

Comment: No hay problema. Un saludo!